# Sqlalchemy: Mapping a class to different tables depending on attribute

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write to an existing database consisting of multiple tables of the following form

```
total_usage_<application>:
    id
    version
    date
```

where `<application>` runs over a number of strings, say "appl1", "appl2" etc. Now I would like to use SQLAlchemy to create a *single* class like

```
class DBEntry:
    id = ''
    application = ''
    version = ''
    date = ''
```

such that an instance `foo` of DBEntry gets mapped to the table `"total_usage_" + foo.application`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: **Q1**: Are all (most of) tables of your application like this or only some? **Q2**: What is this *special* `foo` instance? **Q3**: Are you using [declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html)?

Comment: **Q1**: yes **Q2**: foo only stands for _some generic_ instance of `DBEntry` **Q3**: Yes, but this is not a must

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, please take a look at example below, which is self-contained and might show you one way this can be done. It assumes that you know the `app_name` when you start your program, as well as it assumes that table names follow some naming convention, which obviously you can adapt to your needs or have it completely manually configured by overriding `__tablename__` in each mapped class.
But the *main idea* is that the configuration is wrapped into a function (which can be done also using module import with pre-defined constant beforehand).

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, scoped_session, sessionmaker

def camel_to_under(name):
    import re
    s1 = re.sub('(.)([A-Z][a-z]+)', r'\1_\2', name)
    return re.sub('([a-z0-9])([A-Z])', r'\1_\2', s1).lower()

def configure_database(app_name):
    """ @return: dictionary with all the classes mapped to proper tables for
    specific application.  """
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declared_attr
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

    class Base(object):
        # docs: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/declarative.html#augmenting-the-base
        @declared_attr
        def __tablename__(cls):
            return camel_to_under(cls.__name__) + "_" + app_name

        def __repr__(self):
            attrs = class_mapper(self.__class__).column_attrs # only columns
            # attrs = class_mapper(self.__class__).attrs # show also relationships
            return u"{}({})".format(self.__class__.__name__,
                ', '.join('%s=%r' % (k.key, getattr(self, k.key))
                    for k in sorted(attrs)
                )
            )

    Base = declarative_base(cls=Base)

    class Class1(Base):
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = Column(String)

    class Class1Child(Base):
        id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
        parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(Class1.id))
        name = Column(String)
        # relationships
        parent = relationship(Class1, backref="children")

    # return locals()
    return {
        "app_name": app_name,
        "Base": Base,
        "Class1": Class1,
        "Class1Child": Class1Child,
        }

def _test():
    """ Little test for the app.  """
    engine = create_engine(u'sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
    session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

    app_name = "app1"
    x = configure_database(app_name)

    # assign real names
    app_name = x["app_name"]
    Base = x["Base"]
    Class1 = x["Class1"]
    Class1Child = x["Class1Child"]

    # create DB model (not required in production)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # test data
    cc = Class1Child(name="child-11")
    c1 = Class1(name="some instance", children=[cc])
    session.add(c1)
    session.commit()

_test()
```